# Problems to upload and process txt and csv files on the server

Tags: php, html, hosting

I have a simple form that allows uploading files to the server. In a php file, the file is received, it is moved to a folder on the server and an attempt is made to open it to display its contents on the screen.
In local server everything works great but when uploading it to a pay server nothing works. The file seems not to be received, I do not understand what is happening. These files have been tested on two different servers and it is the same. I check the code but I do not see anything wrong with it and aside in local if it works for me.

This is my form (index.html file):

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>TESTING FILES</title>
            </head>
            <body>

            <form method="POST" action="ProcessData.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="files1" id="files1" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Man" required> Man
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Woman" required> Woman
            <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send">
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

and this is my php file that receives and processes the data sent from the form:

```
      $ar = $_FILES['files1']['name'];
      $type = $_FILES['files1']['type'];
      $size = $_FILES['files1']['size'];
      $route = $_FILES['files1']['tmp_name'];
      $gender = $_POST['gender'];
      $dir = "files/". $ar;
      move_uploaded_file($route, $dir);


            $arch = fopen($ar, "r");
            echo $arch;
            $arch2 = file($ar);
            echo "<br><br>";
            print_r($arch2);
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo $ar;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $type;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $size;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $route;
```

as a result, only the file data is shown but the file content is not shown.

```
     [21-Aug-2018 04:56:52 Europe/Madrid] PHP Warning:  file(HotelList.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/evucnwhr/public_html/ProcessData.php on line 12
```

register the same error when I try to upload a csv file

He reviewed the permits beforehand and they are fine. The problem is that it does not seem to open and read the contents of txt or csv files. I want to extract data from .txt and .csv files to process them but it is not achieved.

What could be happening to generate this kind of errors? Why is the content of the files not shown?

Here is the link to the form, so you can try it and see exactly what happens: http://lqxqjmvh.lucusvirtual.es/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

For Solution,

Please check the permission of the file which you wan to upload or the folder when you want to move the files.

also, you can use **getcwd();** in the directory your aiming to. the function will give you the directory that you need to use for moving your file.